# Sending JSON HTTP request using Guzzle HTTP: Result parameters are not as expected

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, httprequest, guzzle

I want to send a JSON request to an endpoint but the results that I get don't match the parameters requested.

**This is the array**

```
$datas = [
            "institutionCode" => $institutionCode,
            "brivaNo" => $brivaNo,
            "custCode" => $custCode
        ];
```

**This is the response using Guzzle HTTP**

```
try {
      $response = $client->request($verb, $endpoint,
                [
                    "headers" =>
                        [
                            "Authorization" => "Bearer " . $token,
                            "BRI-Timestamp" => $timestamp,
                            "BRI-Signature" => $signature,
                        ],
                    "json" => $datas
                ]
            );

            return $response;
        }
        catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {
            return $e->getResponse();
        }
```

**This is the response from the endpoint**

```
{
    "status": false,
    "errDesc": "Institution Code Tidak Boleh Kosong",
    "responseCode": "03",
    "data": {
        "{\"institutionCode\":\"J104408\",\"brivaNo\":\"77777\",\"custCode\":\"7878787878\"}": ""
    }
}
```

Why does the "data" not match the data array I have given above and instead creates a new pattern with a backslash in it?

**This is the native way using cURL PHP**

if there is someone can turn it into a Guzzle Http, it will help me,
after I tried this code, it also didn't help at all

```
$institutionCode = "J104408";
$brivaNo = "77777";
$custCode = "123456789115";

$payload = "institutionCode=".$institutionCode."&brivaNo=".$brivaNo."&custCode=".$custCode;

$path = "/v1/briva";
$verb = "DELETE";
$base64sign = generateSignature($path,$verb,$token,$timestamp,$payload,$secret);

$request_headers = array(
                    "Authorization:Bearer " . $token,
                    "BRI-Timestamp:" . $timestamp,
                    "BRI-Signature:" . $base64sign,
                );

$urlPost ="https://sandbox.partner.api.bri.co.id/v1/briva";
$chPost = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chPost, CURLOPT_URL,$urlPost);
curl_setopt($chPost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($chPost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($chPost, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($chPost, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resultPost = curl_exec($chPost);
$httpCodePost = curl_getinfo($chPost, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($chPost);


$jsonPost = json_decode($resultPost, true);
return $jsonPost;
```

Comment: Thanks , sorry my english is bad
I use Google Translate to translate it 

Comment: The backslashes are to scape the quotes, but if you want to fix the json structure, Try with    `$datas = [
            ["institutionCode" => $institutionCode],
            ["brivaNo" => $brivaNo],
            ["custCode" => $custCode]
        ]; `

Comment: What's the response you expect?

Comment: Just `json_decode` the response data.

Comment: {
  "status": true,
  "responseDescription": "Success",
  "responseCode": "00",
  "data": {
    "institutionCode": "J104408",
    "brivaNo": "77777",
    "custCode": "123456789001"
  }
}

that is what i want @SIGSTACKFAULT